# How to read JSON boolean and number values?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I send a JSON object to server by creating it as:

```
var input_array =self.input_value();

myJson={ 
    request_type:1,   //send request for problem 1
    list_empty: 0,    //1 is empty, 0 is not empty
    data_list:[]
};

for(var k=0;k<input_array.length;k++)
{
    myJson.data_list[k]=input_array[k];
}
```

On the server

```
var data=req.body;  
console.log("request_type: ",req.body.request_type);  // worked

var m_bool= Number(data.list_empty);
if( m_bool != 0)
{
    console.log("data_list size: ",data.data_list.length);
    for(var i=0;i<data.data_list.length;i++)
    {
        console.log(data.data_list[i]);
    }
}
```

It stopped just  after printing second line. I think it can't read 
"list_empty" field of JSON. I changed to

```
...    
list_empty: false,
...
```

still server did not enter in "if" statement. without the if statement I been able to print the array elements.

I think I am failing to read the value of "list_empty".

how can I get the correct value for the if statement?

Comment: What does req.body.list_empty give you? Can you console.log this?

Comment: @ShawnPike console.log printed  false without " ", just false.

Comment: Interesting - so that value is not being populated for some reason. What does console.log(data) give you? Is it an object?

Comment: "list_empty: 0" - "1 is empty, 0 is not empty" -- Why not simply use `true` and `false`?

Comment: can't read true and false. so trying to judge by number. both failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use type of to identify your cases:

```js
let bo = false;
console.log(typeof bo === "boolean");   // true

let nu = 3
console.log(typeof nu === "number");    // true
```

Comment: but how to know it is true or false? typeof seems only judge if it is a number or boolean.

Comment: I want to know what number or what boolean value it is.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is probably not to blame - I'm guessing you've confused the variable like the rest of us. Using "0" as "not empty" seems dangerous.

```
list_empty: 0,    //1 is empty, 0 is not empty
....
if (m_bool != 0)
    //iterate data
```

You're saying "if empty, iterate my data". But it's not empty, and if it was you'd have new problems. Just fix the logic:

```
if (m_bool == 0)
```